# ImportError :No module named pandas

Tags: django, pandas, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy my app into Amazon Web Service EBS and when i open it, it keeps prompting me this error.

```
 ImportError at /safeplace/location/
 No module named pandas
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://usafe2.epnjkefarc.us-west-
 2.elasticbeanstalk.com/safeplace/location/?lat=-37.877010&lng=145.044267
 Django Version:    1.10.6
 Exception Type:    ImportError
 Exception Value:   
 No module named pandas
 Exception Location:    /opt/python/current/app/api/views.py in <module>, 
 line 15
 Python Executable: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.12
 Python Path:   
 ['/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/current/app',
 '',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7']
```

I have already did pip install pandas and it says i have already satisfied the requirements.

Comment: Which part of your django python file uses pandas, can you show me how you use pandas in django project please.

Comment: @niche.p I was trying to parse my Rest api using pandas because my api is in a Json format in my views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty complicate to get the pandas to run in aws but since you are trying to retrieve a data from your own api which I assume it exists in your models.py and all the data is already there. Therefore you can.

```
a = yourObject.objects.all()
#Make a list to contains all the object
listAttribute1 = []
listAttrubute2 = []
for x in a:
    listAttribute1.append(x.yourattribute1)
    listAttribute2.append(x.yourattribute2)
```

Thus, you can retrieve data from your api without using pandas this way. For more information.

Check here.

http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/

Comment: I guess I have to do you way since for some reason, AWS don't not allow pandas to be installed in. Probably because of the instance environment.

Comment: I am not an expert in using aws so I cannot say much. Pandas works with serveral programs installed such as Visual C++ etc. Therefore, you need to be careful when using virtual environment with pandas. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using python virtual environment instead of the default. Make sure when you install anything after activating the virtual environment.

```
you$ source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
(venv)you$ pip install pandas
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey I just did that, basically it says "Requirement already satisfied"